# how to test multiple models on the same data for significant differences

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, paired-data

I have two sets of data that I am fitting 5 different regression model function types to: 2 polynomials, a power, an exponential, and a gaussian. I am using AIC scores to determine the best fit of the 5, but I want to be able to test them for significant differences. I could use some guidance in how to do this.

I'm assuming I would treat each model's output of estimated values as the sample "measurements" for each model. They are all based on the same two-variable regression, so I think that means they are not independent samples and that they are a 5-way "paired" sample? Not sure what is the best test to use, though.

BTW, I am not a statistician and so request that responses do not assume I understand the jargon.  :-)

Update: If it helps to have the big picture to inform a response, here is what I'm doing:

I have 9 crop attributes taken from plots where the soil was either drained or left undrained. I am fitting models to the data comparing each crop attribute with every other attribute within a drainage treatment, looking for relationships between them. For each pair, I'm trying 5 different models, as listed above, to see what is the best fit. I'm ranking each by AIC to find the best fit, but I want to know if there are any actual significant differences between the 5 models.

Ultimately, I want to take the best model for a drained treatment pair of attributes and compare it to the best model of the corresponding undrained treatment pair so that I can compare the shapes between the models. The question I'm trying to answer is: Is there a tendency for different model shapes between treatments, across all the pairings?

Comment: What is the goal of your analysis?  Is it purely to predict as new observations as closely as possible or develop a model that can be well-interpreted?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I'll edit my post to include the big picture, as there is more to it. I was trying to keep it simple, but there may be more to it than I'm thinking.